# eigenvalues as an optimization problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am thinking on how to compute eigenvalues as the solution of an optimizing problem.

Until now I can think of an optimizing(minimizing) problem as following.

As we know, eigenvalues of a matrix $A_{n\times n}$ are the solution of $|A-\lambda I|=0$ where $|.|$ denotes the determinant of a matrix and $I$ is the identity matrix. So my question is: is it possible to rewrite the function as $\arg\min_{\lambda\in \mathbb{R^n}} |A-\lambda I|$? Is this function convex? on the other hand I am wondering if somebody can help me with a numerical method that I can use to solve the problem.

I will be so so happy if you refer me to a paper, book or tutorial for more information.

Comment: Definitely not convex. Do you know about the [power method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration)?

Comment: Thanks @TedShifrin but I cannot find this method useful in my case. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to formulate the eigenvalue problem as an optimization one.

For a single eigenpair, you have the following

\begin{align}
&\max_\phi &\phi^T A \phi\, ,\\
&\operatorname{subject to} &\phi^T \phi = 1\, .
\end{align}

This one can be reformulated for several eigenpairs as

\begin{align}
&\max_\Phi &\operatorname{tr}(\Phi^T A \Phi)\, ,\\
&\operatorname{subject to} &\Phi^T \Phi = I\, .
\end{align}

You can also maximize/minimize the [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient):

$$\max_\phi \frac{\phi^T A \phi}{\phi^T \phi}\, .$$

See reference 1 for a discussion on these and other versions as well.

#### References

1. Ghojogh, B., Karray, F., & Crowley, M. (2019). Eigenvalue and generalized eigenvalue problems: Tutorial. arXiv preprint arXiv:1903.11240.